# where to declare the data that needs to be accessible to multiple objects?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, polymorphism

I have just started to work with multiple objects/classes and I am having a hard time figuring out how to implement the data structure properly

Assuming  I have a base class

```
class control
{
    protected:
              char* location
              /* node** adjacency_list; This doesn't work  */

};
```

and two different derived classes

```
class carA:public control      
{

}; 

class carB:public control
{

};
```

and a `node` class.

My problem starts when I try to implement a 2D-ish structure like an array of linear linked list (graph) based on location in which the `adjacency_list` needs to point to the right memory space and must be available to all objects.

- If I initialize the `adjacency_list` pointer to NULL at the base
  class constructor, with every derived class object it will be set to
  NULL again.
- If I create the array in the base class constructor, it will create a
  new array for every derived class object.

I tried to find a way with using the copy constructor of the base class in the derived class initialization list, but I couldn't justify/visualize a way that works.

So apart from declaring it globally, what/where is a simple, sensible way to declare this pointer?

I understand this might be extremely trivial, but I just can't see it at the moment.

Comment: You want one `adjacency_list`, shared by all `control` objects?  Make it a `static` member of the class.  (`static node** adjacency_list;`).

Comment: The typical advice is to use `std::vector` and forget about pointers. But then I don't really understand the question

Comment: If it needs to be accessible everywhere, what's wrong with declaring it globally? Or at least in your main function and then passed as a parameter to where it's needed.

Comment: @john   So the class I am taking strictly prohibits the use of global variables. But, my last case scenario was to declare it in main, just like you said. Generally in introductory courses, they ask that all the data is either protected or private, so that's why I was trying to see if there is someway that makes more sense to people . I'll try it with static tomorrow, but thanks everyone.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you so much. That makes so much sense and just the information I needed.

Comment: @LucAux If you declare your data as static and public then in effect you are making it global.

Comment: @john What about a static variable that is declared as a protected data member in a class? Then wouldn't the scope be just the base class and its derived classes?