# The scope of the static member variable (protected) of a class

Tags: c++, class, object

so I am trying to work with multiple classes and objects for the first time.

Assuming I have sth like this

```
class control
{
    public:

            ~control();
    protected:
              /*char* location*/
              static node** adjacency_list;

};
```

I needed the adjacency_list pointer information to be available to all the derived class objects so I declared it as static (as advised in my previous question) in the base class.

My question is: When I define this variable as:

```
node** control::adjacency_list= new node[MAX];
```

in the source file, outside of my constructor, **what is the real scope of `adjacency_list`?**

Obviously the scope resolution operator is there, so I would assume that this variable is only available to the objects of this class and any other class that is derived from the `control` class. But reading about static vs global variable threads got me confused a little bit and I wanted to see if I am missing some information.

**Also would my `~control()` destructor be able to free the memory that is allocated with `new` in this instance?**

Comment: Having the destructor of an instance call `delete` on a `static` member is going to cause you all kinds of trouble

Comment: You've got bad advice. Do not use static data.

Comment: [Static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) are not bound to class instances. They are visible to everyone who can access protected part of the class.

Comment: `static` has about a dozen different meanings, depending on context, so it's not surprising that "reading about static vs global variable threads" gets you confused. That's a different `static`.

Comment: Also note that [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472712/where-to-declare-the-data-that-needs-to-be-accessible-to-multiple-objects) asked about having a member shared between *all instances* of a class, here you are talking about having a member available to derived classes - those are two different things

Comment: *Also* `node** control::adjacency_list= new node[MAX];` shouldn't compile and you should be using one of `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::list` instead anyway

Comment: @UnholySheep My bad for not clearly expressing myself. I want to implement a graph.  So I need a node** variable to implement an array of LLL. I want every object (of different classes all of which derived from the same base class) to have access to this array. But I am having a hard time figuring out where to declare and define this array.

Comment: What do you mean by *"every object have access to this array"*? Do they all share one? Does every object have its own copy? Are the sizes compile time constant or depend on a runtime value?

Comment: @UnholySheep They all share one. There is one graph. Every object has the address (of the first element). But since according to my instructions "every data used needs to be private/protected" I can't define it outside of a class. It isn't supposed to be this hard. I am just not capable of seeing sth so obvious.

Comment: In that case I would just move it into a new class (e.g.: `class graph`) which holds the `node** adjacency_list;` and handles it's initialization and destruction (e.g. via constructor and destructor) and put a `static graph adjacency_graph;` member in your `control` class. Or maybe use the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) though that may be overkill in this case

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks for all the help. I'll have to sleep on it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually using the term "scope" too broadly.   Not everything that (you seem to) describe as scope is actually scope.

The scope is within the class `control`.   Which is why use of the scope resolution operator (`::`) is used, and the full name of the static member is `control::adjacency_list`.

(Technically, there are other definitions of scope in computer science - I'm just using one that arguably makes most sense in C++).

Accessibility of the member is something distinct from scope, and affects what other functions or types can directly access `control::adjacency_list` (the class `control` itself, friends, derived classes and structs).

`control::adjacency_list`, since it has `static` storage duration, will exist until program termination (independently of how `control::adjacency_list` is initialised, or how its value is changed during program execution).

The lifetime of whatever `control::adjacency_list` points at is also distinct from scope (and distinct from the lifetime of `control::adjacency_list` itself) and will depend on how it is initialised.    If you use operator `new []` to do that, the lifetime will be to the corresponding operator `delete []`.

Unless you use specific logic to manage the lifetime of whatever `control::adjacency_list` points at, it is often not a good idea to release it in a destructor of control.    However, there are techniques that can be useful (e.g. use reference counting of class `control`, and the destructor only releases `control::adjacency_list` when the last instance of `control` is destructed).     That sort of decision depends on your requirements and design - there are no absolute answers.

Incidentally, your claimed method of initialisation can't be correct, since

```
node** control::adjacency_list= new node[MAX];
```

would not compile.   The expression `new node[MAX]` (assuming `MAX` is an integral value) gives a result of type `node *`.   That cannot be implicitly converted to a `node **`.